# complexType with nuSoap

Tags: php, xml, wsdl, nusoap

I have this WDSL

```
<xsd:element name="elementname">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="miref"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

Now I have to create that via nuSoap but I can't find anyway to omit de type and name on the complexType and set the complexType inside of an element.

So if I want to create an element I use this code:

```
$server->wsdl->AddElement(  
        array('name' => 'example1', 'type' => ''
        )
);
```

And if I want to create a complexType this other:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'example2',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'id_user' => array('type' => '', 'maxOccurs' => '1', 'minOccurs' => '1'),
    )
);
```

So this are my problems:
1] I need to put that complexType (example2) inside of the other element (example1).
2] The complexType shouldn't have his name inside the tag but the functions addComplexType() and addElement(), dosn't seem to work if I don't give them the Type and the Name. Also in the documentation is typified that it's need: attributes that must include name and type.

Comment: Please describe your issue more accurately. What are you trying to achievie, and what is the problem? Are you trying to invoke service method with soap client or write a method with soap server?

Comment: I'm trying to write the server side and the WSDL must have this exact output. I'll edit to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with nuSoap, but as it's based on native PHP SoapServer, I'm asuming it's similar.

Basicly when working with PHP methods, SoapServer will parse returned objects according to attached XML Schema (XSD).

Whenever you're working with complexType you should have corresponding defined PHP class. StdClass will work too, but it's obviously better to define structure.

```
$response = new stdClass();
$response->sequenceElement = 'value';
return $response;
```

Obviously, sequenceElement name must match XSD class you're refering to (ref="miref").

Moreover, if you add additional data to your $response, it will be ignored by SoapServer, since it's not defined in XSD.

Comment: After reading your edited question, i see it regards WSDL generation by nuSoap. I won't be able to help you in that case, keep working with nuSoap documentation :)

Comment: Thanks anyways, I have the server working and displaying outputs for the requests but it's not showing the exact WSDL that it should :(

Comment: From my personal experience - We used to work on Zend Soap AutoDiscovery to generate WSDL, but with new requirements it has became insufficient. We switched to creating WSDL and XSD manually and I will never return to any sort of auto-generated WSDL/XSD - the control over content you gain when creating these documents manually is great and in long term - more efficient.