# PHP nuSOAP complexType within element tag

Tags: php, nusoap, complextype

I have to build the following WSDL structure:

```
<xs:element name="sobre">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="encabezado" type="tns:encabezadoSobre"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="cuerpo" type="tns:cuerpoSobre"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But it looks like the nuSOAP architecture do  not allow me to do that.

With the following code:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'sobre',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'sequence',
    '',
    array(
        'encabezado' => array('name' => 'aem:encabezado', 'type' => 'tns:encabezadoSobre'),
        'cuerpo'    => array('name' => 'aem:cuerpo' , 'type' => 'tns:cuerpoSobre')

    )
);
```

I have the following structure:

```
<xsd:complexType name="sobre">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="encabezado" type="tns:encabezadoSobre"/>
        <xsd:element name="cuerpo" type="tns:cuerpoSobre"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I have found a similar issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652610/complextype-with-nusoap) but the answers in there did not help me out.

So to sum up what I need to do is to create a element named "sobre", and a complexType within this element.

I have an average of 20 webservices with the same problem so to rebuild it using another framework or php native soap would be the last last last option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'sobre',
'complexType',
'struct',
'sequence',
'',
array(
    'encabezado' => array('name' => 'aem:encabezado',  'minOccurs' => '0', 'maxOccurs' => '1', 'type' => 'tns:encabezadoSobre'),
    'cuerpo'    => array('name' => 'aem:cuerpo',  'minOccurs' => '0', 'maxOccurs' => 'unbounded', 'type' => 'tns:cuerpoSobre')

)
```

);